# How to create looping macro in SAS/ Proc SQL

Tags: sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I need to write code that performs the same action over and over, but using a different macro variable name each time.  I've done this before, but can't quite remember the syntax.

Summary: I need to run the same code using multiple file inputs - all of the input files have a standardized name, with only the term name changed. I need the output file names to be organized in the same standard.

This is what I've come up with but it's not working.  I don't get any errors in the log, it looks like it has run just fine, but there's no output:

```
%macro term;

proc sql;
create table work.output_&term. as
select distinct id, enrl_status 
from work.input_&term.
;
quit;

%mend term;

%let term=Fal22;
%let term=Spr22;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the macro to take a parameter. Since you seem to want to use TERM as the name of the macro variable let's use a different name for the name of the macro itself (they don't have to be different, but it will make it less confusing for humans).

```
%macro extract(term);
proc sql;
create table work.output_&term. as
select distinct id, enrl_status 
from work.input_&term.
;
quit;  
%mend extract;
```

Then you can call the macro passing in different values for the parameter.

```
%extract(term=Fal22)
%extract(term=Spr22)
```

Answer (score 0):

Often like-named data will be stacked in order to perform BY group processing or create a categorical plot.

You can stack all data sets having a common name prefix by using a naming shortcut (:) and the SET option INDSNAME=

Example:

```
data want;
  length term $10;
  set work.INPUT_: indsname=input_table
  keep id enrl_status;
  term = scan(input_table,-1,'_');
run;
```